# Custom post not appearing under custom taxonomy category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

Hello again Wordpress Stack,

I'm having trouble getting my custom post to display under a custom category.

The post in question is this:

```
register_post_type('feature_article',
        array(
            'labels' => array(/* left out for clarity */),
            'query_var' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'excerpt'),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'taxonomies' => array('twin')
            )
        );
```

and the registered taxonomy is here:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'twin_post_taxonomy', 0 );

function twin_post_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(/* for clarity */ );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'twin' ),
        );

    register_taxonomy( 'twin', array( 'feature_article','post'), $args );
}
```

I'm trying to call the post in question here (I called the category "double portrait"):

```
 <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'feature_article', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'article_genre' => $str, 'orderby' => 'modified');  
   $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
 <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

 <?php if ( in_category('double portrait') ) { 
           echo the_title(); 
  } else { 
           echo the_excerpt(); 
  } ?>

    <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Sorry for the long messy code :/

Edit: I am getting the output excerpt instead of title.

Comment: Do you mean the slug is twin and its name is 'double portrait'? Where does 'article_genre' fit in?

Comment: @vancoder The category name is double portrait. Article genre is another custom taxonomy I'm using, that seems to be working fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_category` is only for the built-in `category` taxonomy. If you want to check a custom taxonomy term, use [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term):

```
if ( has_term( 'double portrait', 'twin' ) ) {
```